# Mac OS Big Sur - Homebrew Apache - 48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080

Tags: macos, apache, homebrew, macos-big-sur

I have a problem with Apache on Mac OS Big Sur. After the OS update, the Apache (using Brew) doesn't work anymore.
So I have decided to uninstalled the `httpd` Formula.
Then tested is the preinstalled version of Apache works and it does.

1. So I have stopped the preinstalled Apache `sudo apachectl stop`
2. Unloaded launcher `sudo launchctl unload -w /System/Library/LaunchDaemons/org.apache.httpd.plist 2>/dev/null`
3. Updated the Homebrew

   - `brew update`
   - `brew doctor`
   - `brew upgrade`
4. Installed the httpd again `brew install httpd` (installed successfully)
5. Started the httpd `sudo brew services start httpd`

However checking the status `sudo brew services list` I can see that the httpd service has status `error`.
When I try to start apache using `sudo apachectl start` I'm receiving the error:

```
(48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

I've checked if maybe there is something else running on the 8080 port `lsof -i TCP:8080` but it's not.

I've checked which Apache is used (`which apachectl`) and it seems to be the right one (`/usr/local/bin/apachectl`)

No matter what port I'm trying to use, always there is an error that the address is already in use.

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this problem?

Answer (score 15):

I was facing the same problem.
It appears that bindings to `INADDR_ANY (0.0.0.0)` fail.

To circumvent the bind error, I changed in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf` the following line:

```
Listen 8080
```

to:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
```

Afterwards, I could start apache without the bind error, using the following command:

```
sudo apachectl -k start
```

Comment: Worked for me too! Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem, but needed to run apache on port 80.  First I got it working on 8080 with the solution above by @FrankStappers with:

```
Listen 127.0.0.1:8080
ServerName localhost:8080
```

Next I tried changing the port to 80 in both Listen and ServerName directives.  Restarting left me with these errors:

```
(13)Permission denied: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 127.0.0.1:80
no listening sockets available, shutting down
AH00015: Unable to open logs
```

Ultimately changing Listen and ServerName as follows fixed it:

```
Listen 0.0.0.0:80
ServerName localhost
```

The solution is documented in the **Troubleshooting Non-Sudo httpd Services Start** section of https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions

Answer (score 1):

My solution:

1. `brew services stop httpd`
2. Edit your `httpd.conf` maybe located in `/usr/local/etc/httpd/httpd.conf`

```
Listen 80
ServerName localhost
```

3. Make sure there are no other lines with this keys and save the file.
4. `brew services start httpd`

Answer (score 0):

I've also been facing this issue after my Mac was restarted (after a week of already using Big Sur). I had to completely uninstall the `httpd` from Brew, kill all the processes using port 80, re-install the `httpd`, changing the `httpd.conf` as Frank mentioned, and only then I could get it working (without the need for `sudo`). :

So in short, first change this line in `httpd.conf` to:

`Listen localhost:80`

And then here is the list of command I ran:

```
brew uninstall httpd
kill $(lsof -ti:80)
brew install httpd
```

If the service is not running. You can do: `brew services start http`

Or: `/usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -k start`

Please note, I already had a working system before this. For the full installation guidelines follow the amazing tutorial on [getgrav](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions). They deserve a lot of credit for such a complete tutorial and their support in the comments there!

P.S: [Here](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-bigsur-apache-multiple-php-versions#comment-5170816523) is why you shouldn't use `sudo` to start `httpd`.