# Homebrewed httpd does not work after upgrading macOS Big Sur

Tags: apache, homebrew, httpd.conf, macos-big-sur

I would like to ask a new question on this problem, although lots of similar questions are here, seeming not to solve my problem.

[image]

After upgrading OS to Big Sur(Big Sur 11.2.1), I cannot start apache with homebrew. The terminal says "uccessfully started `httpd`" after command "brew services restart httpd", the process is not executed. Although syntax error is checked by configtest, brew list still shows the status of httpd as error.

Listening port fixing referred below did not work for me.
([Mac OS Big Sur - Homebrew Apache - 48)Address already in use: AH00072: make_sock: could not bind to address 0.0.0.0:8080](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64912014/mac-os-big-sur-homebrew-apache-48address-already-in-use-ah00072-make-sock))

Does anyone has any idea how to fix this problem? Thank you!

Comment: Can you fix the issue?